# Wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) on every page, even info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

I have created a rails 4.0.0.rc1 project on my desktop pc using Ruby 1.9.3. When I try to run it on my laptop I always get the above exception, no matter which page I request. It even happens on /rails/info/properties. Both computers use the same Ruby and Rails version. 
The project still works fine on my desktop PC. I am using a Rubymine development server, I have tried running Rails S in command prompt, but I still get the same error.

I realise this means that I am somehow passing a parameter when I should not be, but I have no idea how I'm doing that. What is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tracked down the gem that seems to be causing this. In this case it seems to be 'Therubyracer' causing this issue for me. For some reason I do not have to include it in my gemfile on my desktop, but my laptop does require it to be included.